# Jasper Async Report - Empty, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Lets start , firstly I get parameters for specific report for exmaple

```
var config = {
    url : "http://exmaple.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reportFolder/exampleReport/inputControls",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;"
    },
}
```

Everything is ok, I get a response with an array of inputs,

The array contains, 2 objects with :

First:

```
{
description: "Date_from",
id: "Date_from",
label: "Date from",
type: "singleValueDate"
}
```

Second:

```
{
description: "Date_to",
id: "Date_to",
label: "Date_to",
type: "singleValueDate"
}
```

Both inputs have a property:

```
validationRules[0].dateTimeFormatValidationRule.format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

So now I want to run a async report (I will pass async parameter false for now, se there is less code here)

```
var params ={
    reportUnitUri: "/reportFolder/exampleReport",
    outputFormat: "html",
    freshData : true,
    saveDataSnapshot : false,
    ignorePagination: true,
    async : false,
    interactive: false,
    allowInlineScripts: true,
    parameters: {
        "Date_from":["2014-08-01"],
        "Date_to":["2015-10-08"]
    }
}
```

So now I try to generate async report:

```
var config = {
        url : "http://exmaple.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        data: params,
        method: "POST"
    }
```

I get a success response, but

```
totalPages: 0,
requestId: "0200cf28-300f-4e76-b99e-e479be4980ba",
reportURI: "/reportFolder/exampleReport/",
status: "ready",
exports[0].id: "c9a5578a-6bc8-4c3e-8a78-9056ef19f456",
exports[0].status: "ready",
exports[0].outputResource :{
    contentType: "text/html",
    outputFinal: true
}
```

When I try to get the output of the report by calling :

```
 http://exmaple.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions/0200cf28-300f-4e76-b99e-e479be4980ba/exports/c9a5578a-6bc8-4c3e-8a78-9056ef19f456/outputResource
```

The report is empty.

Runing the same via :

```
http://exmaple.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reportFolder/exampleReport.html?Date_from=2014-08-01&Date_to=2015-09-08
```

Gives me a filled report,

Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong ? :/
I'm pretty sure that it may be something wrong with the parameters but I tried in various ways and I can't find a solution by myself :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that the parameters passed to the async report were badly formatted, it should be like this:

```
parameters: {
    reportParameter: [
        {name : "Date_from",value : ["2014-08-01"]},
        {name : "Date_to",value : ["2015-10-08"]}
    ]
}
```